# C# OOP : Using interface with type parameters in base concrete class

Tags: c#, oop, .net-core

I hope the title is descriptive of the problem, I had trouble phrasing the problem I am trying to solve.

I'm using .NET Core 2.1

I've recently started at a C# shop after doing Python for the last 5 years so my strongly typed oop is a bit rusty. Here is what I have and what I'm trying to do:

I a base repository interface that defines basic CRUD functionality for database entities:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> where TEntity : class
{
   TEntity FindById(TPrimaryKey id)
   void Create(TEntity entity);
   void Delete (TEntity entity);
}
```

I inherit from this interface to define the interface that my repository class implements:

```
interface IProductRepository : IRepository<Product, int>
{
   void SomeProductRepoMethod(int someParam);
}
```

Then I implement all interface methods in my concrete class:

```
public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
   public Product FindById(int id)
   {
      // lookup
   }

   public void Create(Product product)
   {
      // save 
   }

   public void SomeProductRepoMethod(int someParam)
   {
      // do product repository specific stuff
   }
   ....
}
```

Now, what I want to do is fairly straightforward. I want to add a overload of `Create` on `IRepository` that takes an `IEnumerable` of `TEntity` :

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> where TEntity : class
   ...
   void Create(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
   ...
```

But I'd like to define the **implementation** of this overload **once**:
So I was thinking I could make a abstract  base repository class to put the above implementation. The problem I am facing is I'm not sure how or even if I could do this cleanly with the modelI have now. I tried to make a base class that implements `IRepository`, but that would mean
passing type params to the base class and on to the interface:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey>
{
    public abstract TEntity FindById(TPrimaryKey id);

    public abstract void Create(TEntity entity);
    public abstract void Delete(TEntity entity);
    public void Create(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        foreach(TEntity entity in entities)
        {
            Create(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my concrete repository:

```
public class ProductRepository : BaseRepository<Product, int>, IProductRepository
{
   public override Product FindById(int id)
   {
      // lookup
   }

   public override void Create(Product product)
   {
      // save 
   }

   public void SomeProductRepoMethod(int someParam)
   {
      // do product repository specific stuff
   }
   ....
}
```

This doesn't feel quiet right to me since I am passing the same type params in both `IProductRepository` and `ProductRepository`. I feel like
I'm close but not there and I'm not sure what the best practice approach here would be. If anyone could suggest an approach I would really 
appreciate the feedback. Apologies for the length of the post but I felt I needed to clearly describe what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: You could just create an extension method instead.  The downside is that you cannot override it.

Comment: The only problem with an extension method is testability, more particularly the isolation of methods during testing.

Comment: @ColinM How would there be problems with testing.  You create a mock of the `IRepository` and call the extension method to test it.  They are just as testable as any other static method.

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the extension method which may change over time, and whether there's anything in there which could perform I/O operations. This isn't a "no" or shut down to that solution, more of a disclaimer for future changes. It is too late to rephrase my previous comment, I think "problem" was a strong word to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having the same type parameters in an interface and an abstract class is not that big of a deal. Using your abstract class solution is okay, unless your `ProductRepository` needs to inherit from some other class.

Actually, with your abstract class, your `IRepository` interface doesn't need to exist anymore. Just handle everything with `BaseRepository`!

Another solution to this problem is an extension method. In a static class, you can write this:

```
public static void Create<TEntity, TPrimaryKey>(this IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> repo, IEnumerable<TEntity> entities) where TEntity : class {
    // do your foreach loop here
}
```

Now you can call this method on any `IRepository` instance just like this:

```
repository.Create(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I should have clairified a bit, I would still want to use the `IRepository` and `IProductRepsitory` interfaces because I will have some implementations that won't use the base concrete class. The extension method is an interesting approach though, I am gonna give that a try - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the way I'd do it.  I'd break the inheritance between `IRepository` and `IProductRepository`:

Here are your interfaces:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> where TEntity : class
{
    TEntity FindById(TPrimaryKey id);
    void Create(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
    void Create(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
}

internal interface IProductRepository
{
    void SomeProductRepoMethod(int someParam);
}
```

Then let your base class inherit `IRepository` as you've done:

base class:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> : 
    IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> where TEntity : class
{
    public abstract TEntity FindById(TPrimaryKey id);
    public abstract void Create(TEntity entity);
    public abstract void Delete(TEntity entity);

    public void Create(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        foreach (TEntity entity in entities)
        {
            Create(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

and then you derive your base class and also implement your `IProductRepository`:

```
public class ProductRepository : BaseRepository<Product, int>, IProductRepository
{
    public override Product FindById(int id)
    {
        // find
    }

    public override void Create(Product product)
    {
        // save 
    }

    public void SomeProductRepoMethod(int someParam)
    {
        // do product repository specific stuff
    }

    public override void Delete(Product entity)
    {
        // delete
    }
}
```

I think your derived class' specificity to being a `Product` repository is an implementation detail on `BaseRepository`.